# How can I pass typename to a class that I don't want to templatize?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following problem (simplified version):

```
Interface X;
class Y : public X { ... }
class Z : public X { ... }

class A
{
    map<int, X> m;
    init() { X bla = new Y or Z; map.insert(...) }
}
```

I would like to specify either Y or Z at creation time of A, thus getting a different functionality based on type specified. Currently I could "templatize" A, but that would mean EVERY function I define for A will have to have the template specified, even though I need to use it only in one method. Also, I am using g++ 4.2.4, which means I can't separate my implementation of functions from the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... even though I need to use it only in one method ...

What is usually done in this case is moving the common functionality, which is not templatized, to a base class, and defining a templatized `A` that inherits the base functionality. I.e.:

```
class A_base {
    // common things go here, they can be implemented in a .cpp file.
};

// This is the part that depends on T
template<class T>
class A : public A_base
{
    map<int, T> m;
    void init() { T *bla = new T; map.insert(...) }
};
```

This is a common technique to reduce code bloat. In case that `A_base` needs to call a method of `A`, you can make it `virtual`.

Comment: This seems to fit the bill for me perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Worth noting that `init` needs to be `virtual` for this thing to work correctly.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: no it is not. It depends on who is calling `init()`. If `init` is the constructor, for example, then not only it doesn't have to be `virtual`, but actually it cannot be such.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like templates are indeed overkill, and some form of dependency injection is more appropriate. You could pass the particular instance of `X` in to `A::init`, for example:

```
init(X &bla) { map.insert(...); }
```

Or pass in a factory function:

```
init(X (*factory)()) { X bla = factory(); map.insert(...); }
```

Or do either of these but pass the instance or factory function to the constructor of `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good approach in general - I need to remember it.

Answer (score 2):

If, as it seems from the use of `new`, it's actually `map<int, X*> m` and `X* bla=...`, you can "templatize" just `init()`, creating an `Y` or `Z` depending from its template parameter.

In alternative, you could have a factory method for `X`-derived objects that returns an `Y *` or `Z *` depending on an `enum`; or have the caller of `init` specify a factory function that returns the appropriate `X`-derived type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was something I considered, but init is called from within the A class - which now has to store extra data to know what type to instantiate. I am trying to avoid adding extra variables to the class - it has too many already. =)